# UIView group opacity in single view heirachy

Tags: ios, uiview

I am writing a UI library in which i would like to be able to have the alpha of the UIViews as if the UIViewGroupOpacity info.plist ket was set.  See following links:

[Make UIView and subviews translucent as one layer, not individually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6458427/make-uiview-and-subviews-translucent-as-one-layer-not-individually)

[iOS controlling UIView alpha behaviour for subviews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8581994/ios-controlling-uiview-alpha-behaviour-for-subviews)

But, as I am writing a lib, I dont want the projects to have to set this global key, and effect the behaviour of the main project.

Is there any other way of achieving this?  I dont want to cycle through all the subviews and set alpha of each subview, as the project that includes my lib might have this key enabled...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes there is, you can set [`shouldRasterize`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CALayer/shouldRasterize) of the view's layer.

```
containerView.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
// Not setting rasterizationScale, will cause blurry images on retina displays:
containerView.layer.rasterizationScale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
```

This will have the same effect as `UIViewGroupOpacity` but only for `containerView` and it's subviews.

Comment: Does this work if the superView is THE super view for the hierarchy?  Doesn't appear to have any affect in iOS 7.

Answer (score 1):

**For iOS 7.0 and later:**

Since iOS 7.0, this can be controlled for each `CALayer` individually through the `allowsGroupOpacity` property. By setting it to `YES`, you get the same behavior as if `UIViewGroupOpacity` was set, but just for that particular layer.